# egrep two identical numbers and two identical letters n times

Tags: linux, bash, unix, grep

Hi I've been having trouble with the command egrep. Here is my question:
Lets just say I was running in a for loop on these words:

```
99aa88bb99aa88bb 9a9a 11bb11bb 11bb11dd 12aa12aa
33aa33bb33aa33bb
```

I only want to print the word if it has two identical numbers **and** two identical letters **and** the word repeats itself. for example in this case the only words that should print are:

```
99aa88bb99aa88bb
11bb11bb
33aa33bb33aa33bb
```

because each word has at least one or more set of two identical numbers and the two identical letters and then it repeats itself

Here is another example, I am going over these words in a loop:

```
 aa99aa99 00aa00bb00aa00bb 44aa44aac
 2222aaaa2222aaaa 11cc11cc11cc11cc
```

The only words that should print are

```
 00aa00bb00aa00bb
 11cc11cc11cc11cc
```

because of whats mentioned above.
I am really struggling on how to do this My current command that isnt working is:

```
egrep "^((([0-9])\3([a-z])\4)(([0-9])\6([a-z])\7))\1*$" tmp
```

The reason why its not working because it prints for me words like:

```
11bb11dd
```

which are not allowed.

any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Is it fair to call they will be always even length words? or they can vary?

Comment: @Inian yes it is fair to say that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$ cat ip.txt
99aa88bb99aa88bb 9a9a 11bb11bb 11bb11dd 12aa12aa
33aa33bb33aa33bb 
 aa99aa99 00aa00bb00aa00bb 44aa44aac
 2222aaaa2222aaaa 11cc11cc11cc11cc 

$ grep -owE '(([0-9])\2([a-z])\3([0-9])\4([a-z])\5)\1+|(([0-9])\7([a-z])\8)\6' ip.txt
99aa88bb99aa88bb
11bb11bb
33aa33bb33aa33bb
00aa00bb00aa00bb
11cc11cc11cc11cc
```

This has two cases

1) `(([0-9])\2([a-z])\3([0-9])\4([a-z])\5)\1+` which has 8 character construct repeating at least once - that is the key, using `\1*` will falsely match `11bb11dd`

2) `(([0-9])\7([a-z])\8)\6` this has 4 character construct repeating exactly once

If you have them on separate lines, this would do

```
grep -xE '(([0-9])\2([a-z])\3([0-9])\4([a-z])\5)\1+|(([0-9])\7([a-z])\8)\6'
```

If `11bb11bb11bb` has to be matched as well, use `\6+`

Or, use this very clever suggestion by [Nahuel Fouilleul](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1454708/nahuel-fouilleul)

```
$ grep -owE '((([0-9])\3([a-z])\4)+)\1+' ip.txt
99aa88bb99aa88bb
11bb11bb
33aa33bb33aa33bb
00aa00bb00aa00bb
11cc11cc11cc11cc
```

- `(([0-9])\3([a-z])\4)+` forms the base, 4/8/12/16/etc characters which consists of repeating digit followed by repeating alphabet
- that is then captured in outer group and then repeated at least once

Note that if input is large, and you have PCRE `-P` option, use that instead of `-E` as backreferences would be much faster, at least in case of `GNU grep`

Comment: why not `grep -oE '\b((([0-9])\3([a-z])\4)+)\1\b'` ? or `grep -oEw '((([0-9])\3([a-z])\4)+)\1'`

Comment: @NahuelFouilleul that's very clever indeed.. won't match `11bb11bb11bb` though.. which I am not sure if OP wants to or not

Comment: indeed because of word boundaries, however could be fixed adding `+` after `\1`